# Prove $\mathrm{codim}(\mathrm{Im}(I+K))<\infty$ for a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory, banach-spaces, compact-operators

As part of a solution of an exercise in functional analysis, I saw the following claim: If $K:X\to X$ is a compact linear operator in Banach space, then $\mathrm{codim}(\mathrm{Im}(I+K))<\infty$.

This was presented without proof in an introductory book on functional analysis, right after learning about Fredholm theory of compact operators.

How can one prove this claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By compactness of $K$, the closed unit ball in $\ker(I+K)$ is compact, so $\ker(I+K)$ has finite dimension. Therefore, $X = \ker(I+K) \oplus S$ for some closed subspace $S$ of $X$. The operator $I + K$ restricted to $S$ has an inverse $T : \operatorname{Im}(I+K) \to S$. You can show (by way of contradiction, using compactness of $K$) that $T$ is continuous at $0$ (and hence continuous). Then $\operatorname{Im}(I + K)$ is closed.

To demonstrate that $\operatorname{Im}(I + K)$ has finite codimension, suppose to the contrary that the codimension of $\operatorname{Im}(I + K)$ is infinite. There is a sequence $\operatorname{Im}(I + K) = S_0 \subsetneq S_1 \subsetneq S_2 \subsetneq \cdots$ of closed subspaces of $X$ with $\dim(S_{n+1}/S_n) = 1$ for every $n$. Riesz's lemma gives normalized vectors $x_n\in S_n$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(x_n,S_{n-1}) \ge 0.5$. If $n > m$, then $(I + K)x_n, (I + K)x_m$, and $x_m$ belong to $S_{n-1}$, forcing $$\|Kx_n - Kx_m\| = \|(I + K)x_n - (I + K)x_m + x_m - x_n\| \ge \operatorname{dist}(x_n,S_{n-1}) \ge 0.5$$ Consequently, $(Kx_n)$ has no convergent subsequence, contradicting compactness of $K$.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the fact that you mostly used elementary results without relying on advanced material.